# matlab parfor and spmd doesn't work

Tags: matlab, parfor, spmd

The script is as follows:

```
    Lambdass = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000];
    numcores = feature('numcores'); % get the number of cpu cores
    num_slices = floor(length(Lambdass)/numcores); % get the number of slices for parallel computing
    if mod(length(Lambdass), numcores)~=0
        num_slices = num_slices + 1;
    end
    for slice_i=1:num_slices
        if slice_i~=num_slices
            Lambdas = Lambdass(((slice_i-1)*numcores+1):((slice_i)*numcores));
        else
            Lambdas = Lambdass(((slice_i-1)*numcores+1):end);
        end

        % start the parallel processing
        myparpool = parpool(length(Lambdas))
        parfor li = 1:length(Lambdas)
        % spmd
            lambda = Lambdas(li);
            save_path1 = sprintf('results/lambda_%f/', lambda);
            if ~exist([save_path1, '/fs_results.mat'], 'file') 
                do_something_and_save_results(lambda, save_path1);
            end
        end
        delete(myparpool)
    end
```

This script could be run correctly in one computer, but in another computer, the `parfor` seems to not work correctly and there are some warning information as follows, and the `parfor` finally runs without parallel mode, just seems the `for` in sequential. Could anyone help give some advice, please?

```
    Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... Warning: Could not launch SMPD process manager. Using fallback parallel mechanism.
    > In SmpdGateway>SmpdGateway.canUseSmpd at 81
    In Local.hSubmitCommunicatingJob at 15
    In CJSCommunicatingJob>CJSCommunicatingJob.submitOneJob at 81
    In Job.Job>Job.submit at 302
    In InteractiveClient>InteractiveClient.start at 327
    In Pool.Pool>iStartClient at 537
    In Pool.Pool>Pool.hBuildPool at 434
    In parpool at 104
```

Comment: Well, what is the difference between the computers? (hardware, OS, version of MATLAB).  The reason presumably lies somewhere in there, rather that in the specifics of your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a software installation problem or system configuration problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: @Edric, and therefore should be on superuser?

Comment: @hubber winston: Try to reinstall the Parallel Computing Toolbox.

Comment: Or try MathWorks' forums: [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/).

Comment: @nkjt, thank you! I've made a post in https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/171265-warning-could-not-launch-smpd-process-manager-using-fallback-parallel-mechanism. If convenient, could you help visit it?

Comment: @horchler, thank you! I've made a post in https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/171265-warning-could-not-launch-smpd-process-manager-using-fallback-parallel-mechanism.

Comment: @A.Donda, thank you! I'll try it! and I've made a post in https://cn.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/171265-warning-could-not-launch-smpd-process-manager-using-fallback-parallel-mechanism. If convenient, please check it.

Comment: @Edric, thank you! I'll close this question when nkjt and A.Donda checked my responses.